# Response.redirect and data-rel="back" in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm developing webapp using asp.net webforms.
my problem is i am not getting history when i click on back button, Here is my code:

```
 <div class="header" data-role="header" data-theme="f"  >
        <div>
            <a class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="f" data-role="button" data-corners="true"  data-rel="back"
                class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow  ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-corner-all " data-shadow="true" href="#"
                data-iconshadow="true" data-icon="back" data-ajax="true">Back</a> 

                <a class="ui-btn-right btnLogout"
                    href="#" data-theme="f" data-role="button" data-corners="true" id="btnLogout"
                    class="ui-btn ui-shadow  ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-corner-all " data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"
                    onclick="Dologout(); return false;">Logout</a>
        </div>
```

the above code is in master page. I have some selection with drop down in one page and search result on another page, i'm navigating search result using `response.redirect()` method.
but when i click on back button it clears everything. I want to show history. I have made

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            // jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
            // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), especially when going back, hence disabling it.
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
        });
```

Please help me!

Comment: You click on `back` button it clears everything. What does it mean? To which page you are getting redirect?

Comment: the page having dropdown box, which contains search criteria ,on clicking search button , it redirects to result page, so here is the back button I want to go back to search page from result page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was only With internet Explorer.It Works well With FF and chrome. I used session for holding variable and restore the values to dropdown when clicking back
I didnt find any other work around than using session.